# Windows, Synergy, and EnableHexNumpad

Tags: windows, unicode, synergy

Windows 8.1, Synergy 1.5.1-r2307

It seems Synergy does not support EnableHexNumpad in Windows, where much like traditional ALT-codes, any Unicode character can be inserted when holding alt, then pressing numpad-plus and a hexadecimal number.  For example:

```
ALT 3232: á
ALT +0CA0: ಠ
```

However, with synergy running, EnableHexNumpad doesn't appear to work:

```
ALT 3232: á
ALT +0CA0:
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Using ALT 3232 looks odd. It works, but just because 3232 = 160 mod 256, so ALT 160 is a more natural way,

Comment: Ah... I should add that EnableHexNumpad can be enabled by adding REG_SZ "EnableHexNumpad" = "1" to "HKCU:\Control Panel\Input Method".  Changes take effect after restarting explorer.exe.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: You are correct.  3232 is 0CA0 in decimal, and is intended to show that traditional ALT decimal input is limited to 256, in the code page of the system (I think?); in my case, the code page is Latin Extended (I think...)

Comment: Could you try updating? Synergy 1.5 is very old now.